# ¿Como descargar un XML (desde URL) en un objeto tipo Document en Java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, xml

Estoy trabajando en android studio, con un fichero XML en firebase y quiero almacenarlo en un Document de Java para leerlo posteriormente.

Tengo eso:

```
    public void leerXMLtoDocument() {
        // Create a storage reference from our app
        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();


        storageRef.child("/localizaciones.xml").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                System.out.println(":Archivo conseguido");
                System.out.println(uri);
               
                }
            }
```

El enlace uri lleva al XML bien pero no se como almacenar el contenido.

Gracias!

Comment: A que te refieres con un Document de Java? Que error obtienes en el LogCat?

Answer (score 0):

Asi podria estar funcionando:

```
public void leerXMLtoDocument() {
   // Create a storage reference from our app
   StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();

   storageRef.child("/localizaciones.xml").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            File file = new File(uri.getPath());
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = documentBuilder.parse(file);
            try {
               Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
               tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
               tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
               Writer out = new StringWriter();
               tf.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/localizaciones.xml"));
            } catch (Exceptio e) {
               // 
            }
        }
}
```

Primero lo leas en un objeto `File` desde el `uri` y luego haces un documento con `DocumentBuilder`. Para guardar el objeto tipo `Document` tienes que transformarlo con objeto `Transformer`.

---

**Recursos en ingles:**

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975197/convert-file-uri-to-file-in-android

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704827/java-reading-xml-file

[3] https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/2796ac8e-36f9-46b5-b963-c211e63d2a6a/y

Answer (score 0):

```
//Directorio destino para las descargas
String folder = "descargas/";

//Crea el directorio de destino en caso de que no exista
File dir = new File(folder);

if (!dir.exists())
  if (!dir.mkdir())
    return; // no se pudo crear la carpeta de destino

File file = new File(folder + name);

URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
conn.connect();
System.out.println("\nempezando descarga: \n");
System.out.println(">> URL: " + url);
System.out.println(">> Nombre: " + name);
System.out.println(">> tamaño: " + conn.getContentLength() + " bytes");

InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

int b = 0;
while (b != -1) {
  b = in.read();
  if (b != -1)
    out.write(b);
}

out.close();
in.close();

try {
 ...
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  System.out.println("la url: " + url + " no es valida!");
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

System.exit (0);
```

No sé si esto te funcione...